# MUSE use local video

Tags: video, html5-video, mp4, muse

I am using MUSE CC to build a small kiosk site for my business - i'm not a coder...

Been trying to figure out a way to create a series of buttons that when each is clicked it loads a different video in a lightbox video player, but the video is hosted locally rather than the web as the kiosk won't have a connection to the internet.

So my site structure is root/video/video1.mp4 video2.mp4 and so forth.

The index.html is in root.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the file to your assets library first. Then when you do the export of the site it'll add the file to the assets folder and then you can use code below to use the video in an iframe locally.